# Как отредактировать страницу ошибки 404 в React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404

пишу свой сайт на React, js. Возникла необходимость отредактировать страницу 404, где её можно найти, или написать свою и где-то указать ссылку на неё вместо текущей?
Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Вот страница по умолчанию:
[image: Стандартная ошибка 404]

Comment: Забыл добавить, на скриншоте ошибка ответа от сервера, а я имел ввиду именно ошибку если по несуществующей ссылку произошел переход внутри сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать это, прописав в app.js код в самый конец:

```
{ path: '*', element: <NotFoundPage/> }
```

NotFoundPage - страница 404, которая сделана самостоятельно.